# Magento 2 - CMS Content Won't Save

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, cms, save, static-content

I'm having a crazy issue where I'm trying to copy over CMS content and it seems that when there are certain words, the content does not save.  It just refreshes the admin page and brings me back to the main list of pages without any messaging saying that the content was saved.  So far, "from" is the only word it's having trouble with, even though that word appears twice before.  I think this is an issue in Magento 1 as well.  This is absolutely the craziest thing I've ever seen in magento.  I tailed for errors and there are none.  I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

An old post, but I was looking for the solution few days ago, so maybe I can help someone.

I had a similar issue with Magento and it turned out it was not Magento's problem. It was ModSecurity installed on the server which prevented all the requests containing "select" and "from" words in this order. They were considered as "SQL injection" risky requests so they were blocked before even sent to Magento.

Disabling the rule of ModSecurity: 300016

(insert[[:space:]]+into.+values|select._from.+[a-z|A-Z|0-9]|select.+from|bulk[[:space:]]+insert|union.+select|convert.+(._from)

helped and my request were working.

More:
https://www.google.com/search?q=rule+300016+mod+security&oq=rule+300016+mod+security&aqs=chrome..69i57.4642j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8